# Chrome extensionのアイコンがデフォルトではツールバーに表示されない

Tags: chrome-extension

manifest.jsonにはbrowser_actionを記載しています。

```
    "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "Check Periodically",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": {
        "16": "images/icon16x16.png",
        "32": "images/icon32x32.png",
        "48": "images/icon48x48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128x128.png"
    }
  },
```

ところが、アイコンがデフォルトでは表示されず、ツールバーの「拡張機能」ボタンを押すと「アクセス不要 これらの拡張機能は、このサイトの情報の表示、変更を必要としてません」の下にアイコンが表示されており、手動で表示するように設定しなければいけません。
browser_actionを設定していればすべてのページが対象になるのではないのでしょうか？ 他に必要な記述があるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

manifest.jsonのpermissionsに"http://*/*", "https://*/*", を加えたら「アクセス不要」の下に表示されることはなくなりました。
それと現在FirefoxからChromeへの移行中なので最近の拡張機能の仕様に疎かったんですが、新しくインストールされた拡張機能のアイコンは最初だけツールバーに表示され、その後は手動で固定しない限りツールバーには表示されないんですね。ということでこの問題も自己解決しました。